# How to fill missing values when reindexing a categorical index?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first post to SO, so please forgive my transgressions. I have a dataframe for which I make a categorical index using `cut`.  I then add the missing intervals, like so

```
n = np.arange(6)
a = [0. , 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1. ]
b = [0. , 1. , 2.5, 2.5, 5. ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b} )
df.set_index(pd.cut(df.b, n), inplace=True)
bins = pd.interval_range(0, 5)
df = df.reindex(bins)

          a    b
b               
(0, 1]  0.5  1.0
(1, 2]  NaN  NaN
(2, 3]  0.7  2.5
(2, 3]  0.9  2.5
(3, 4]  NaN  NaN
(4, 5]  1.0  5.0
```

I want to backfill the NaNs in each column but the argument `method` is not implemented for CategoricalIndex.reindex.  Is there another way to accomplish this?  I'm using Pandas 0.22.0

Comment: `df.bfill()` should work I think

Comment: Yeah... maybe just change that line to `df = df.reindex(bins).bfill()`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use fillna function in pandas with mentioning backfill

```
df.fillna(method='bfill')
```